# Python Pandas- Groupby column to obtain two peaks in the Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python Pandas to groupby a column called "Trace". For each trace, there is a "Value" column with two peaks that I am trying to transfer to a different dataframe. The first problem is that the when I use groupby, it doesn't keep the rest of the data from the row of the value I want to select. For example, if a Pandas dataframe had 6 columns, then I want to preserve all six columns after I use groupby. The second problem is that the two maximums I want are not the two greatest values in the column, but rather "peaks" in the dataset. For example, the attached image shows the two peaks whose values I want. I want the greatest values from each of the two peaks to be exported to a new dataframe with row values from other columns in the previous dataframe.

In the following code, I want to groupby the "Trace" column and pick the two peaks in the "Value" column, while still preserving the "Sample" column after choosing the peaks. The peaks I want to choose would be 52 and 21 for Trace 1 and 61 and 23 for Trace 2.

```
d = {"Trace": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], "Sample": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], "Value": [1,2,3,7,52,33,11,4,2,21,10,3,3,7,15,61,37,16,6,3,11,23,4]}
```

Any suggestions? I have been using .groupby("Trace") and .nlargest().[image: PEaks]

Comment: I'm sure there are many approaches you could take.  In order for anyone to make an educated guess, please provide an [mcve].  It may also be helpful to review [ask].

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer. I revised the question and inserted some code to further clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of the "peak" confuses me, unless you hardcode the Trace values I don't think you will go far.

On a more sensible stance, for someone searching here, I will post the solution o getting `groupby`, `nlargest` - getting all the fields while you are at it -

```
df.groupby(['Trace']).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns=['Value']))
```

**Output**

```
          Sample  Trace  Value
Trace                         
1     3        4      1     12
      4        5      1      9
2     13       4      2     15
      14       5      2     11
```

Here, if you are looking for the two "peak" values by `Value` column grouped by `Trace`, this should be an elegant solution

Comment: I revised the question to clarify. What I mean by peaks are if you plotted the "Value" column for each trace, then you would see two "peaks" in the graph corresponding to 52 and 21 for Trace 1 and 61 and 23 for Trace 2. I do not want the two maximum values in the Trace (I wanted 21 in Trace 1 instead of 33). Does this make more sense?